# como cambiar la localizacion ,de GoogleMap?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

estoy trabajando en una app usando googleMaps , donde el usuario puede ver su localizacion actual o buscar otra ciudad por el nombre desde un EditText.La app me da error cuando quiero buscar otra ciudad , solo funciona cuando busco el nombre de la ciudad donde estoy ,pero al buscar otra ciudad por otro nombre ,la  app se  ha detenido ....
Si Alguien me podria  ayudar o decirme donde esta mi error seria muy agradecido 
Ahi esta Mi codigo, lo que intente de hacer...

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);      
    getLocationPermission();
    geolocate();
}
private void initMap() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
        getDeviceLocation();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
private void geolocate() {
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
     ciudad=bundle.getString("Ciudad");
    Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
    List <Address> list= new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        list=geocoder.getFromLocationName(ciudad,1);
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("GeoLocation","EXCEPTION" + e.getMessage());
    }
    if (list.size()>0){
        Address address=list.get(0);
        Log.e("GeoLocation","EXCEPTION" + address.toString());
        moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude()),DEFAULT_ZOOM);
    }
}
```

la funcion para obtener la ubicacion actual del dispositivo

```
 private void getDeviceLocation(){
    Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                    }else{
                        Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e("MapsActivity.this", "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){

    Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    MarkerOptions options= new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Location");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
}
```

Comment: Que error te da ala hora de buscar?

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference

Comment: creeria que tu mMap es nulll porlo tanto no puede hacer el cambio

Comment: Exactamente me parece null al debugear ,Pero esta declarado en el metodo onReady...

Comment: estas ejecutnado tu metodo geolocate() al crear la actividad, aun no ha cargado el mapa por lo tanto nmap aun es null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo `geolocate()` debe ejecutarse hasta que el mapa este cargado;

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   mMpap=googleMap;     
   geolocate();
  //demas codigo
  }
```

Comment: Gracias @Igner Rodriguez , me ayudomucho  tu repuesta